# MPMoviePlayerViewController to stream Mp3's

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to stream an mp3 using MPMoviePlayerViewController. I realize this was (obviously) meant to be used for movies, but I read that I could use it to stream mp3's as well.

Once the MPMoviePlayerViewController loads, the "Loading..." screen comes up and a couple of seconds later it just closes down. The problem doesn't seem to be with my url since I can plug it into a browser and the mp3 downloads just fine.

Here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"OpenFlowVC: url: %@",url);
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    playerVC.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerVC];
    [playerVC autorelease];
```

Example URL: http://dl.soundowl.com/12kj.mp3

The strange thing is, this works for some mp3's but not others.
Any input would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the real format and encoding of each MP3, try to use some tool that would give you all this information ([Try this one free](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/mediainfomac.html))
They may be all files with mpp3 as extension but not all the same way encoded. Compare a working with a non working mp3.

Comment: I will try this and post back. Thank you for the response